# Game-Engine fly glitch

Tags: game-engine, physics

I was recently working on a blender game. It was cloning the idea of flappy bird.. I was doing it for my own purposes to teach myself (not to put up a clone on the app store.) So I made a cube( I haven't textured anything yet) and made it a rigid body after I put in a motion for the spacebar key. Then set the force on the motion option to 20. The gravity of the world is 9.80. Then put an always sensor on the Y axis and started to flap. When I flap to a certain point it glitches out hard on me. My cube goes out of control and it starts spinning around. My camera (which is parented to that object) Spins out of control too. It then falls into the abyss. I'm on Blender Game Engine and I need help on getting it to stop the glitch.

Comment: it would be helpful if you [upload a .blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to inspect it and avoid long comment questions

Comment: Sounds like you have physics colliding where they shouldn't, try turning on the physics visualization so you can see what's happening.